# How do I run a stable Windows XP kvm guest on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: windows-xp, ubuntu-10.04, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu

I have three Windows XP guests running on a recently upgraded 64-bit Ubuntu 10.04 system.  Occasionally (on the order of once every few days), one of the guests will become non-responsive and the kvm process on the host which is running that guest will start consuming 100% CPU.  It will continue to do so until it is killed.  When restarted, it will be fine for a while, and then the issue repeats.

The kvm command line used to run all three guests is this:

```
/usr/bin/kvm -S -M pc-0.12 -enable-kvm -m 1024 -smp 1 -name bigdog21vmxp1 \
    -uuid ea47ff84-125b-16f7-9a4d-a6d0d8bab46a \
    -chardev socket,id=monitor,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/bigdog21vmxp1.monitor,server,nowait \
    -monitor chardev:monitor \
    -localtime \
    -boot c \
    -drive file=/var/lib/libvirt/images/windowsxp-1.qcow2,if=ide,index=0,boot=on,format=qcow2 \
    -net nic,macaddr=54:52:00:02:06:0e,vlan=0,name=nic.0 \
    -net tap,fd=58,vlan=0,name=tap.0 \
    -chardev pty,id=serial0 \
    -serial chardev:serial0 \
    -parallel none \
    -usb \
    -usbdevice tablet \
    -vnc 127.0.0.1:1 \
    -k en-us \
    -vga cirrus \
    -soundhw es1370
```

Why do the systems misbehave this way sometimes?  And what configuration can I change in order to fix it?  Or, if the problem is due to a bug in kvm, what is the process for isolating a kvm failure so that the developers have a chance of fixing it?

Comment: Have you tried using a different image type to see if the problem continues?  I'd try a raw image file as it takes a lot of code out of play.  Also is the image on local storage or being served via NFS?

Comment: Oh my.  I forgot I'd posted this question.  I also forget how I resolved the issue, but my Windows XP guests haven't been hanging for a while, so I guess I did somehow.

Comment: Yeah I didn't realise how old the question was either.  I wonder how it popped back onto the first page of questions.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I have to debug this is to remove all but the necessary arguments and add the removed arguments until it breaks again. That's the only way I could find my problem last time (on uec 10.10).

Answer (score 0):

What are the chances that the issue occurs whenever the Windows guest tries to restart (e.g. after an automatic update)? I always got freeze-on-restart behavior from Windows guests under libvirt+kvm on Ubuntu Jaunty; now that my host is running Debian Squeeze, it doesn't happen any more.